# What is the best way to Hash Password in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, password-hash

Recently I tried Hashing a password on insert in CodeIgniter as follows,

```
$this->load->library('PasswordHash',array(8, FALSE));
$psw = '1234';
$hash = $this->PasswordHash->HashPassword($psw);
```

But I met with an Error saying "Unable to load the requested class: passwordhash". Please help me with this, or what is the best way to do it.

Comment: `PasswordHash` is CI Library?

Comment: You can try this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/7045061/270037

Comment: You might want to take a look at: https://github.com/HashemQolami/CodeIgniter-PBKDF2-Library

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
$this->load->library('phpass');
```

More reference: https://github.com/jenssegers/CodeIgniter-Phpass-Library

OR

Use `MD5()` or `sha1()` php function to get hash value.

Comment: I did it in $this->load->library('phpass'); way, but when I validate the Login in same way it returns 0 results. why is that?

Comment: 0 means i am not get ur words explain neetly

Comment: I created a user with the password = 'admin1234' by hashing it using phpass, where it stores the hased string in database, In user login I want to check the number of rows by matching User ID & Password(Hashing the user's input using phpass), So when it matches it should return '1'.