# MD5 Salt Login System

Tags: php, authentication, system, md5

Hey guy's i'm trying to make a login system which uses MD5 encryption for the password. I have the encrypting to work and all it's just for some reason when i enter the password "palmer" into the login page and click the login button i made it send me to a page where it tells me encrypted password and using "palmer" as the password it outputs this "Duncan Logged in using password 4844fd4088ef5278ad18f892808ebda8 - palmer". THe password in the database when encrypted is "4669a6b46c8d891b373cfcd664dff6". Why are the two passwords different? I am using the same Salt(the salt is "a123b123".

Below is my code which encrypts password on register:

```
$password = $_POST['password'];

$md5pass = md5($salt.md5($password));
```

Below is my login code.

```
<?php
session_start();
include('config/config.php');

$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$pass2 = md5($salt.md5($password));

$check = mysql_query("SELECT `email`,`password` FROM user WHERE (`email`='$email' AND       `password`='$pass2')") or die(mysql_error());

$count = mysql_num_rows($check);

//if($count == 1) {
$_SESSION['user'] = strtoupper($user);
//header('Location: /panel/index.php');
echo("Duncan Logged in using password $pass2 - $pass");
//} else {
//$_SESSION['errormsg'] = "<div id='error'><strong>Error:</strong> Invalid Username or Password!</div>";
//header('Location: index.php');
//}
?>
```

Comment: "i'm trying to make a login system which uses MD5 encryption for the password" - MD5 is broken: you know that right?

Comment: What do you mean broken?

Comment: Please escape your `$_POST` inputs as you put them in your query, no point in having a login if it's trivial to bypass.

Comment: I mean broken as in broken: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5

Comment: You can crack a 'normal' password in about six seconds on a modern day pc.See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1581610/help-me-make-my-password-storage-safe

Comment: Ok i see, what is another good way to encrypt? @Dunhamzzz Which parts do you mean? sorry i'm new at php :S

Comment: @Duncan Palmer see http://bobby-tables.com

Answer (score 7):

you have to store your salt – and please, use a random salt, this way two users with the same password will get a different digest! – somewhere for later use:

```
$salt = sha1(getRandomSalt());
$digest = sha1($password.$salt).'$'.$salt; // use sha1 instead of md5
```

later you can check the provided password with the same salt:

```
list($stored_pw, $stored_salt) = explode('$', $stored_digest);
if($stored_pw == sha1($user_provided_pw.$stored_salt)) {
  echo 'user provided correct password';
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should really use bcrypt for this. There is more on bcrypt on previous Stack Overflow post [How do you use bcrypt for hashing passwords in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795385/how-do-you-use-bcrypt-for-hashing-passwords-in-php)

bcrypt is considered the most secure way to implement password hashing with salt because it is slow - much slower than an MD5.

Answer (score 2):

Just a little comment to knittl's solution from above:

You need to replace the line

```
if($stored_pw = sha1($user_provided_pw.$stored_salt)) {
```

by

```
if($stored_pw == sha1($user_provided_pw.$stored_salt)) {
```

to get it working.

(I tried to add it to knittl's post, but it says edits need to be at least 6 characters long)