# Best way to encrypt/prepare passwords for insertion into a database

Tags: php, mysql, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Secure hash and salt for PHP passwords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401656/secure-hash-and-salt-for-php-passwords)

What is the best way to prepare a password for insertion into a database, i am aware of md5, but i was wondering if there where some more features/encryptions i could do to it.

Thanks!

Comment: I normally use sha1 but passwords are unretrievable at that point.

Comment: Recommend you take a look at: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/46716/what-should-every-programmer-know-about-web-development

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really don't want to encrypt passwords, but rather a hash of the password which you just 'match' against.

Storing passwords is very insecure and encryption can be broken, a one way hash cannot*

References on SO:

- [How do you use bcrypt for hashing passwords in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4795385/158014)
- [How can I store my users' passwords safely?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1581610/158014)

**yet, that I know of*

Comment: Unless the use of rainbow tables (and that's why the password are salted).

Answer (score 1):

A standard practice is to [salt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29) the password before encryption.

> In cryptography, a salt consists of random bits, creating one of the
>   inputs to a one-way function. The other input is usually a password or
>   passphrase. The output of the one-way function can be stored rather
>   than the password, and still be used for authenticating users. The
>   one-way function typically uses a cryptographic hash function. A salt
>   can also be combined with a password by a key derivation function such
>   as PBKDF2 to generate a key for use with a cipher or other
>   cryptographic algorithm. In a typical usage for password
>   authentication, the salt is stored along with the output of the
>   one-way function, sometimes along with the number of iterations to be
>   used in generating the output (for key stretching). Early Unix systems
>   used a 12-bit salt, but modern implementations use larger lengths from
>   48 to 128 bits. Salt is closely related to the concept of nonce. The
>   benefit provided by using a salted password is making a lookup table
>   assisted dictionary attack against the stored values impractical,
>   provided the salt is large enough. That is, an attacker would not be
>   able to create a precomputed lookup table (i.e. a rainbow table) of
>   hashed values (password + salt), because it would take too much space.
>   A simple dictionary attack is still very possible, although much
>   slower since it cannot be precomputed.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use [sha1()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sha1.php) to encrypt my passwords

Comment: SHA-1 does not encrypt. It hashes. There's a huge difference...