# How To Add "User Account" Functionality To Basic PHP Software?

Tags: php, cloud, user-accounts

I hired a programmer to make a basic program in for me that is written in PHP.

I am hosting it on my own web host.

It is basically a web crawler that returns data on certain websites that are entered into the database.

This software was created without any "user account" functionality- it is just a single instance that is not even properly protected by a login/password button.

I want to finish developing this cloud-hosted software and then be able to sell it to people on a monthly subscription. Obviously I will need a way to create an account for every person that signs up- so they can each access their own account of the software with their own database of whatever websites they want to enter into the software(in other words just how every cloud software works).

My question is definitely a newb one, but basically I want to know, what technology is used to do this? What kind of program/service/code is used to add simple "user account functionality to a basic cloud software?

P.S. I would ask the guy who made it but he took my money and ran after making a a piece of junk.

Comment: Well since it's written in PHP, you're best to use......PHP. Easily written in an IDE like Netbeans. As for the functionality; you're best to research about databases and how PHP interacts with them (i.e. mysqli/pdo).

Comment: You could try taking a look [this authentication tutorial](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/php/php14p1.html) for building your own, or [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9529849/what-should-i-use-for-user-authentication-in-php) which mentions a library you can use that will have implemented the core functionality.

Answer (score 0):

The way that this is done is to modify the PHP to add a login feature. There is unlikely to be an out of the box solution that will work. Rather than having to create a new database every time someone signs up, you would modify the existing database to add a user column to each table, and then update the code to only display the data for the currently logged in user.

Unless you want to spend a few months learning PHP and whatever database you are using, you're going to want to hire another programmer to do this for you. Someone good would charge $200-300 for this. Or you can try taking the lowest bidder for $50 or so, and hope they don't run off too.