# even the email and password are correct still i am getting email or password incorrect and i cannot go to next page by using pdo in php?

Tags: php

please help me with this because whenever i open this i am getting the same error.In my database i inserted an email and password but now when i insert the same into the login form i am getting that the email or password is incorrect even though they are correct which i had entered
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1zn3.png)

user.php

```
<?php 

class User{
    protected $pdo;

    function __construct($pdo){
        $this->pdo = $pdo;
    }

    public function checkInput($var){
        $var = htmlspecialchars($var);
        $var = trim($var);
        $var = stripcslashes($var);
        return $var;
    }

    public function login($email, $password){
        $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT 'user_id' FROM 'users' WHERE 'email' = :email AND 'password' = :password");
        $stmt->bindParam(":email", $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $tempo = md5($password);
        $stmt->bindParam(":password", $tempo, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();

        $user = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        $count = $stmt->rowCount();

        if($count > 0){
            $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user->user_id;
            header('Location: home.php');
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

login.php

```
<?php 

if(isset($_POST['login']) && !empty($_POST['login'])){
    $email =$_POST['email'];
    $password =$_POST['password'];

        if(!empty($email) && !empty($password)){
                $email = $getFromU->checkInput($email);
                $password = $getFromU->checkInput($password);

                if(!filter_var($email , FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
                    $error = "Invalid format";
                }else{
                    if($getFromU->login($email, $password)==false){
                        $error = "The email or password is incorrect!";
                    }
                }
    }else{
        $error = "Please enter username and password!";
    }
}

?>
<div class="login-div">
<form method="post"> 
    <ul>
        <li>
          <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Please enter your Email here"/>
        </li>
        <li>
          <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password"/><input type="submit" name="login" value="Log in"/>
        </li>
        <li>
          <input type="checkbox" Value="Remember me">Remember me
        </li>
        <?php
        if(isset($error)){
                echo ' <li class="error-li">
      <div class="span-fp-error">'.$error.'</div>
     </li>';
        }
        ?>
    </ul>
     </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Please do not roll your own password hashing scheme. PHP provides [``password_hash()``](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [``password_verify()``](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) please use them. And here are some [good ideas about passwords](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet). If you are using a PHP version prior to 5.5 [there is a compatibility pack available here](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Answer (score 0):

@Mohandattu.
To debug this, what I can suggest do following.

- First check the database, how the password has been saved.
- Then dump your actual password i.e   `md5($password);`
- Then cross check both, I'm thinking it might be different, sometimes if your password column length is less it will fail to insert an actual encrypted value into the database, in that scenario it will trim the value and inserted.

**Another approach**

- First fetch the record using email, then compare the password.
  For more info please look into this - [Login in code will just login with md5 encrypted password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10680112/login-in-code-will-just-login-with-md5-encrypted-password)

Comment: well  the type is varchar and the length is 255 , i had already changed the value in database but still  i am getting the same resut

Comment: Have you cross-checked with DB value and your dump? is both are equal?

Comment: sorry but i am a newbie well my database password value is 123456 but what is a dump value and didn't create any register site

Comment: @mohandattu
Okay not an issue, if you notice your password is not encrypted, generally if you encrypt using `md5('123456')`, the value will be something like this - `e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e`

but in your DB it is storing as **123456**, it supposed to be encrypted before it's saving.

Comment: as per your code, your are encrypting your password before fetch 
`$tempo = md5($password);` // this line will encrypt your password so it will become like this `'e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e'`, but in your db the password is '123456', so both are different, that's why your are not getting any records.

Comment: so can u tell me how to convert my database passwordvalue to encrypted form.then what is the solution to this problem what i have to change in the code

Comment: @mohandattu, 
- Before savin/inserting password, we've to encrypt and save, how to encrypt? md5($password); in the same way before fetching also we've to encrypt.
for better way PHP provides password_hash and password_verify inbuilt we can use this as well.
**so can u tell me how to convert my database passwordvalue to encrypted form**, in your script you can do like this `echo md5('123456')`; exit; if you run this it will give you some encrypted string, replace that string in your database.

Comment: yes i did it i got a encrpted value as202cb962ac59075b964b07152d234b70
and the same i replaced in my database still the result is same i am getting the same thing

Comment: @mohandattu, could you please paste the error you are getting.

Comment: i am getting the same image in the above description of my problem

Comment: @mohandattu, I'm at the office, I can't able to access that image, that's the reason I'm asking.

Comment: sorry The email or password is incorrect! this is the error i am getting

Comment: Please check this code, and go through the comments, https://gist.github.com/bharadhwaj-g/cef58888e22bd9f4cf4c4d954d14fafe