# Using Blowfish for Encryption with PHP

Tags: php, security, blowfish

I am working on a registration form where I need to encrypt password, I've heard that it is recommended for me to use the Blowfish encryption for passwords, How do you implement a blowfish encryption using PHP crypt() function? also, I am planning to retrieve the password later for logging in.

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://www.chilkatsoft.com/p/php_blowfish.asp).

Comment: You shouldn't "encrypt" passwords, but use a one-way hashing function. See: [How do you use bcrypt for hashing passwords in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4795385/911182)

Comment: Also read: [How can I store my users' passwords safely?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1581610/how-can-i-store-my-users-passwords-safely/1581919#1581919)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The short answer is use `crypt` with a salt beginning with the characters **$2a$**, a two digit *cost* parameter, **$**, and 22 digits from the alphabet **./0-9A-Za-z**. That only works on systems that support the Blowfish encryption algorithm. However, PHP 5.3 implements it natively. See [PHP manual — crypt](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php) for more details.

Example:

```
crypt('rasmuslerdorf', '$2a$07$somesillystringforsalt')
```

The salt string triggers the appropriate algorithm. The two digit *cost* parameter is the base-2 logarithm of the iteration count for the underlying Blowfish-based hashing algorithm and must be in range [04 – 31]. In the example 07 tells the algorithm to use 2<sup>7</sup> or 128 iterations. The higher this number, the longer it will take to execute BUT, in the context of hashing user passwords, that is a **GOOD** thing.

[This answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6337021/911182) explains in more detail what BCrypt is,how it relates to Blowfish, and why you should use it. There are many other [related topics here on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php+bcrypt).

---

[phpass](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/) is an excellent, easy to use password hashing framework that works on all systems, using Blowfish if it’s supported, and falling back to other algorithms if it’s not.

Answer (score 4):

You should never need blowfish to encrypt a password like this.  The registration form should be over HTTPS,  which will handle defense against an attacker on the wire.   The password its self should be hashed (**never encrypted**).  bcrypt is a good password hash function based on blowfish.  But there are plenty of posts related to secure password storage on SO.

Comment: After [Heartbleed vulnerability](http://heartbleed.com/), i guess nothing is completely secure.