# Implementing password hashing/salting algorithm from crackstation.net

Tags: php, security, passwords, hash, salt

I am trying to implement a password hashing/salting algorithm from [crackstation.net](http://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm#phpsourcecode), but I am unsure how implement it.

Storing the password upon user registration seems to be as simple as passing the password into create_hash().

```
$password = create_hash($_POST['Password'];
```

I'm not following how to validate upon user login. validate_password($password, $good_hash) returns either true or false, and takes $password as parameter, so it seems like a no brainer except for the second parameter $good_hash. Where does this param come from?

It is my understanding that password is turned into a hash value every time its used, and that the hash value is what is stored and compared. So why would I have both the $password and $good_hash values?

Quick overview of the functions:

```
function create_hash($password){
    calls pbkdf2()
}

function validate_password($password, $good_hash){ 
    calls pbkdf2() 
    calls slow_equals() 
}

function slow_equals($a, $b){
}

function pbkdf2($algorithm, $password, $salt, $count, $key_length, $raw_output = false){
}
```

Of course a different, better method for this would also be just as helpful.
Thank you

Comment: i would assume $good_hash is the stored hashed password and $password is the raw one submitted for a login

Comment: Do not role your own, use [PHPass](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1581610/how-can-i-store-my-users-passwords-safely/1581919#1581919)

Comment: Two PBKDF2 notes: First, use has high an iteration count as you can and maintain sufficient performance during peak load.  Second, never ask for more output length than the native hash (SHA-1 is 20 bytes, SHA-224 is 28 bytes, SHA-256 is 32 bytes, SHA-384 is 48 bytes, and SHA-512 is 64 bytes).  A different method is password_hash() and password_verify(), available in PHP since 5.5, and since 5.3.7 with a compatibility library, per the [PHP.net Password Hashing FAQ](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`good_hash` has been stored in the DB at this point and is the known "good hash."  Retrieve it from the DB and compare it to the `password` the user has been submitted that has now been hashed with the same algorithm.

Comment: So I just retrieve the hash stored in the db, and pass it in with the raw password obtained from $_POST. It's so obvious, boy do I feel silly now.