# .val() doesn't work - can't find solution

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 var login = $("#login").val();
 var password = $('#password').val();


 $('.login-button').click(function() {
  alert(login);
 });
});
```

HTML

```
<form method="post" class="login">  <p id="login-error"></p>
<p>
  <label for="login">Username:</label>
  <input type="text" name="login" id="login" placeholder="username">
</p>

<p>
  <label for="password">Password:</label>
  <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="password">
</p>

<p class="login-submit">
  <button class="login-button">Login</button>
</p>

<p class="forgot-password">Fill your username and password.</p>   </form>
```

It shows nothing! What's up with it? Any solution? The id names are correct

EDIT:
I have another problem. Dont want to open another question for that. I'm trying to get ajax answer from validate.php (it is in /views/admin/validate.php - it runs when opening domain.com/validate)

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
$('.login-button').click(function() {
var login = $("#login").val();
var password = $('#password').val();
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '/view/admin/validate.php',
  data: {
  login : login,
  password : password
  },
  success: function(data){
    $('#login-error').html(data);
  }
});
});
});
```

validate.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$user = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['login']);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string(sha1($_POST['password']));
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  `users` WHERE name =  '$user' AND pass =  '$password' AND privileges = 'superuser'");
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($query);
if($num_rows == '0') {
echo "Username and Password are incorrect! (Maybe you don't have permission!)";
}
elseif($num_rows == '1') {
$expire = time()*60*60*60*60;
setcookie("user","$user",$expire);
$_SESSION['user'] = $user;
include '/views/admin/admin.php';
}
?>
```

It should return Username and Password are incorrect! (Maybe you don't have permission!) - but it doesn't.. Any solution??

Comment: SLaks is correct, here's a working demo for you: http://jsfiddle.net/UUUqa/

Comment: **Do not store passwords in plain text**.

Comment: If you have a different question, ask a different one. Asking two questions in one post is going to cause some confusion.

Comment: It works! Thanks, but about this - Do not store passwords in plain text. Which is correct way to store password :)

Comment: @TigranMuradyan - here are some solutions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1581610/how-can-i-store-my-users-passwords-safely

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var login = $("#login").val();
```

When this line runs, the input is empty.

You need to get the value after the user types something.

Comment: Right... Forgot about that! Thx! Will accept the answer in 10 mins.

Comment: I edited the post, there is another question, please help to find solution for that.

Comment: @TigranMuradyan: You need to `return false` from the event handler to prevent the default action of submitting the form.

Comment: where exactly should i write return false?

Comment: @TigranMuradyan at the end of click handler

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.login-button').click(function() {
  var login = $('#login').val();
  alert(login);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it :

```
$('.login-button').click(function() {
  alert($("#login").val());
 });
```

or :

```
$('.login-button').click(function() {
      var login = $("#login").val();
      alert(login);
     });
```

or :

```
var login = "";
$('.login-button').click(function() {
      login = $("#login").val();
      alert(login);
     });
```