# having an error invalid login or username after adding sh1 into my script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, sha1

i have made my own login authentication script into php, it's working fine when i use it without using "sh1"... and successfully uploaded username and password into my database, but i want to encrypt password into database due to security reason, now i'm using `$hash_key=sha1($_POST['password']);` into script, when i check into database it successfully encrypted see my pic..

[image]

But as i logged in, it's giving me an error

[image]

So, i decided to remove "sh1" and directly save my password into database once to check..

[image]

and it's working fine:

[image]

But using `sha1` it's working and showing an error message `invalid username and password`..

[image]

Please help, what's wrong into my code??

Here is a code for `insert.php`

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","Bhawanku","members");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$hash_key=sha1($_POST['password']);
$sql="INSERT INTO admin
VALUES
('', '$_POST[username]','$hash_key')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
{
    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
echo "1 record added";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

and here is a code for `login.php`

```
<?php
include("config.php");
session_start();
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{

// username and password sent from Form
$myusername=addslashes($_POST['username']);
$mypassword=addslashes($_POST['password']);

$sql="SELECT * FROM admin WHERE username='$myusername' AND passcode='.sha1[$mypassword]' ";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
$active=$row['active'];
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);


// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
if($count==1)
{
$_SESSION["myusername"];
$_SESSION['login_user']=$myusername;

header("location: welcome.php");
}
else
{
echo "Your Login Name or Password is invalid";
}
}
?>
<form action="" method="post">
    <label>UserName :</label>
    <input type="text" name="username"/><br />
    <label>Password :</label>
    <input type="password" name="password"/><br/>
    <input type="submit" value=" Submit "/><br />
</form>
```

Comment: your problem is here '.sha1[$mypassword]' must be "'.sha1[$mypassword].'"

Comment: `sha1` is not very secure, see this Q&A http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1581610/how-can-i-store-my-users-passwords-safely

Comment: @NinjaDevelopers: it's giving `expected: semicolumn error` ??

Comment: **Danger**: You are **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that you need to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.  **Danger**: 
You are using [an unsuitable hashing algorithm](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php) and need to [take better care](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet) of your users' passwords.

Comment: okay first of all please solve my problem, it's not loggin in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line in select query

```
passcode='.sha1[$mypassword]'

$sql="SELECT * FROM 
admin WHERE username='$myusername' 
AND passcode='.sha1[$mypassword]' ";
```

should be

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM 
admin WHERE username='$myusername' 
AND passcode='".sha1($mypassword)."'";
```

**UPDATE**

The problem appears to be while saving the password the field was set to varchar(30) sha1() will return string longer than that. so that needs to be increased. And the password needs to be re-inserted since old passwords will not work.

Now

```
$myusername=addslashes($_POST['username']);
$mypassword=addslashes($_POST['password']);
```

Should be replaced as

```
$myusername=mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['username']));
$mypassword=mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['password']));
```

The query is already mentioned above.

And if there are more that one user with the same username and password then the condition

```
if($count==1)
```

will fail

Comment: can u echo the query and then use the same on mysql ? and remove addslashes in `$mypassword=addslashes($_POST['password']);` u can use mysql_real_escape_string for both username and password.

Comment: I meant just `echo $sql ;` then copy the query and try it directly on phpmyadmin.

Comment: Yes, bro i copied that encrypted key from phpmyadmin and paste it into login, still giving that invalid error..

Comment: and i changed it into `mysql_real_escape_string` still giving the same error

Comment: How about `$sql="SELECT * FROM 
    admin WHERE username='$myusername' 
    AND passcode=".sha1($mypassword).";` ?

Comment: still giving the semicolumn eror

Comment: hold on what is the size of password field on DB ?

Comment: there u are all ur sha1 is getting trimmed to 30 chars. Make it varchar(100), reinsert the password and relogin it should work !! I have been doing it for ages without any issue.

Comment: but u need to reinsert the passwords before u use them in select since making it 100 will not work with already inserted data. Create a new account with a new password and then login with that password

Comment: But someone suggesting that this using ` if($count==1)` may cause you an error

Comment: ok i suppose its a test DB. In phpmyadmin run this query `update admin set passcode = sha1('testpass')` , then use this password for a login check. remove the addslashes from ur code. Well if there are more than one user with the same username and password then yes it will create issue. In addition u echo the query and try directly on php myadmin and check what u get if any error post it here.

Comment: Okay, there is an other issue when i use `if($count=1)` after removing `=` it's logged in successfulyy but problem is it accpets every password..

Comment: i mean type into password field whatever it'll logged in you

Comment: yes = means assignment == means comarison u need to use ==

Comment: It's working finally man!! i just restarted my computer and its working thanks man:)

Answer (score 0):

For password field you don't need to use addslashes()

```
$mypassword = sha1($_POST['password']);

$query = "SELECT * 
  FROM admin 
  WHERE username = '$myusername' AND passcode ='$mypassword'";
$rs = mysql_query($query);
if ($rs && mysql_num_rows($rs) > 0)
{
  // login ok
}
else {
  // login failed
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query fromation has problem try below line and check

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM admin WHERE username='".$myusername."' AND passcode='".sha1[$mypassword]."'";
```

Comment: Notice: Use of undefined constant sha1 - assumed 'sha1' in C:\Users\Raj\PhpstormProjects\lesson08\login.php on line 13