# What are the downsides of using my own hashing algorithm instead of popular ones available?

Tags: hash, password-hash, hash-function

I am a noob in algorithms and not really so smart. But I have a question in my mind. There are a lot of hashing algorithms available and those might be 10 times more complex than what I wrote, but almost all of them are predictable these days. Recently, I read that writing my own hashing function is not a good idea. But why? I was wondering how a program/programmer can break my logic that (for example) creates a unique hash for each string in 5+ steps. Suppose someone successfully injected a SQL query in my server and got all the hashes stored. How a program (like hashcat) may help him to decrypt those hashes? I can see a strong side of my own algorithm in this case, that it is known by no one and the hacker has no idea how it was implemented. On the other hand, well-known algorithms (like sha-1) are not unpredictable anymore. There are websites available that are highly eligible to efficiently break those hashes. So, my simple question is, why smart people do not recommend to use self-written hashing algorithms?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Secure hash and salt for PHP passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/401656/1146608) and [How can I store my passwords safely](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1581610/1146608). "On the other hand, well-known algorithms (like sha-1) are not unpredictable anymore." SHA-1 and SHA-2 [are broken](https://www.google.com/webhp?&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=sha%20hash%20broken). There are better hash algorithms to use. In short, [use bcrypt, PBKDF2 or scrypt](http://security.blogoverflow.com/2013/09/about-secure-password-hashing/).

Comment: @PatrickM - Referring to best-practise seems not to be the answer to this question. The question is more about the reasons, _why_ inventing an own algorithm is not recommended. Of course the links are useful anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Security by obscurity can be an advantage, but you should never rely on it. You rely on the fact that your code stays secret, as soon as it becomes known (shared hosting, backups, source-control, ...) the stored passwords are propably not safe anymore.

Inventing a new safe algorithm is extremely difficult, even for cryptographers. There are many points to consider like correct *salting* or *key-stretching*, making sure that similar output does not allow to draw conclusions about the similarity of the input, and so on... Only algorithms withstanding years of attacks by other cryptographers are regarded as safe.

There is a better alternative to inventing your own scheme. With inventing an algorithm you actually add a secret to the hashing (your code), only with the knowledge of this code an attacker can start brute-forcing the passwords. A better way to add a secret is:

1. Hash the passwords with a known proven algorithm (BCrypt, SCrypt, PBKDF2).
2. Encrypt the resulting hash with a secret server-side key (two-way encryption).

This way you can also add a secret (the server side key). Only if the attacker has privileges on the server he can know the key, in this case (s)he would also know your algorithm. This scheme also allows to exchange the key when necessary, exchanging the hash algorithm would be much more difficult.