# Ajax jquery redirecting is not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, redirect

I have a login form when user logs in he has to redirect with to participant-screen.php

Ajax script

```
    $.ajax({
      url: "controller.php",method: "POST",
      data: { loginData: $("#loginForm").serialize(),'action': 'login' },
      dataType: "text",
      success: function(response) {
        $("#showMessage").html(response);
        if (response == 'success') {// response coming as success but not redirecting
 // redirecting script
        }
      }
  });
```

Comment: I'm not a PHP programmer but that looks open to SQL injection!

Comment: I am a PHP dev and I confirm ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Can Try below method for Redirecting

```
// similar behavior as an HTTP redirect
window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");

// similar behavior as clicking on a link
window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
```

Answer (score 4):

You cannot use a `header()` redirect when you use ajax. Instead you have to redirect in the javascript part of your ajax when the request has been processed successfully. See for example [How to redirect to another webpage in JavaScript/jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-to-redirect-to-another-page-in-jquery).

Note that you would have to send information back from your php script (for example json) so that you can take the appropriate action in javascript.

Apart from that:

- You have an sql injection problem, you should use a prepared statement instead of injecting variables directly into your query.
- You should not use `md5()` for password hashing. See for example [How can I store my users' passwords safely?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1581610/how-can-i-store-my-users-passwords-safely)

Comment: full url or page url imean amerytech.net/learningcurve/participant-screen.php or participant-screen.php ....? @jeroen

Answer (score 2):

`header()` not supported in jquery you need to user `windows.location.href`

```
window.location.href="your url";
```

Comment: full url or page url  imean http://amerytech.net/learningcurve/participant-screen.php  or  participant-screen.php   ....?

Answer (score -1):

I got my solution

```js
$.ajax({
url: "controller.php",
method: "POST",
data: { loginData : $("#loginForm").serialize(), 'action':'login'},
dataType: "json",
success: function (response) {
 if(response["success"]==true)
 {
  $("#showMessage").html(response['message']);
  location = '/learningcurve/participant.php?loginid='+response["id"];
  window.open(location);
 }else{
  $("#showMessage").html(response['message']);
 }
},
error: function (request, status, error) {
 $("#showMessage").html("OOPS! Something Went Wrong Please Try After Sometime!");
}
});
return false;
```

i used data type text replaced with json