# password related validation error in codeigniter

Tags: php, html, forms, codeigniter, validation

The follwing code is related to the signup part in my web application developed using codeigniter

```
<?php
class user extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper(array('form','url'));
        $this->load->library(array('session', 'form_validation', 'email'));
        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->model('user_model');
    }

    function index()
    {
        $this->register();
    }

    function register()
    {
        //set validation rules
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('fname', 'First Name', 'trim|required|alpha|min_length[3]|max_length[30]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('lname', 'Last Name', 'trim|required|alpha|min_length[3]|max_length[30]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email ID', 'trim|required|valid_email|is_unique[user.email]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|matches[cpassword]|md5');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('cpassword', 'Confirm Password', 'trim|required');

        //validate form input
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            // fails
            $this->load->view('user_registration_view');
        }
        else
        {
            //insert the user registration details into database
            $data = array(
                'fname' => $this->input->post('fname'),
                'lname' => $this->input->post('lname'),
                'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
                'password' => $this->input->post('password')
            );

            // insert form data into database
            if ($this->user_model->insertUser($data))
            {
                // send email
                if ($this->user_model->sendEmail($this->input->post('email')))
                {
                    // successfully sent mail
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('msg','<div class="alert alert-success text-center">You are Successfully Registered! Please confirm the mail sent to your Email-ID!!!</div>');
                    redirect('user/register');
                }
                else
                {
                    // error
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('msg','<div class="alert alert-danger text-center">Oops! Error.  Please try again later!!!</div>');
                    redirect('user/register');
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // error
                $this->session->set_flashdata('msg','<div class="alert alert-danger text-center">Oops! Error.  Please try again later!!!</div>');
                redirect('user/register');
            }
        }
    }

    function verify($hash=NULL)
    {
        if ($this->user_model->verifyEmailID($hash))
        {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('verify_msg','<div class="alert alert-success text-center">Your Email Address is successfully verified! Please login to access your account!</div>');
            redirect('user/register');
        }
        else
        {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('verify_msg','<div class="alert alert-danger text-center">Sorry! There is error verifying your Email Address!</div>');
            redirect('user/register');
        }
    }
}
?>
```

I have done the relevant validations for the relevant fields. But when trying to signup I get the error password does not match with the confirm password field though i entered same values for the password and confirm password fields! How can i correct it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a while since I used codeigniter(CI). I think you're hashing (md5) the first password but not the confirmation password. What happens if you try the following:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|matches[cpassword]');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('cpassword', 'Confirm Password', 'trim|required');
```

If this fixes your problem you can hash if afterwards, like so:

```
//insert the user registration details into database
            $data = array(
                'fname' => $this->input->post('fname'),
                'lname' => $this->input->post('lname'),
                'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
                'password' => md5($this->input->post('password'))
                # Replace md5 with cryptographic hashing function that isn't deprecated.
            );
```

I'd recommend not using md5, especially not without a salt. You might want to check out [`crypt()`](http://www.php.net/crypt), [`password_hash()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and the top answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1581610/how-can-i-store-my-users-passwords-safely).

Comment: thanx i am new to CI so if i am hashing again where and how should i put it?