# PHP mysqli ->bindValue SQL error

Tags: php, mysql

I have a SQL query:

```
if($stmt = $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO users(login, passwd, logged, register, last_login) VALUES(:login, :passwd, FALSE, NOW(), NULL")) {
    $stmt->bindValue(':login', $login, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindValue(':passwd', md5($passwd), PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
} else {
    echo "query error <b>".$connection->error."</b><br>";
}
```

and it returns this error:

> Connection error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ':login, :passwd, FALSE, NOW(), NULL' at line 1

How can I fix it?

I am using MariaDB on Linux Fedora.

Comment: You sure it's connected with PDO, and not MySQLi?

Comment: Yes, sorry You are right, I changed title.

Comment: `bindValue` is PDO, mysqli only has unnamed placeholders.

Answer (score 2):

That error indicates that you're using a MySQLi connection, and not a PDO one. If this is true, you have a few errors here - as PDO and MySQLi doesn't mix.

MySQLi doesn't offer named placeholders (like `:placeholder`, as PDO does), so you'll have to use `?` instead. Furthermore, the MySQLi uses `bind_param()` and not `bindValue()` (which is a PDO function).

The code for MySQLi would look like this

```
if ($stmt = $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO users(login, passwd, logged, register, last_login) VALUES(?, ?, FALSE, NOW(), NULL)")) {
    $password = md5($passwd);
    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $login, $password);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
} else {
    echo "query error <b>".$connection->error."</b><br>";
}
```

There was also a `)` missing at the end of your query, which I have added in the snippet above.

---

It's also worth noting that `md5()` isn't a good function to store passwords with. PHP offers `password_hash()` with `password_verify()` which you should use instead. The [manual](http://php.net/password_hash) holds examples for those functions.

It's also worth noting that errors should only be displayed like that in development. For live versions, you shouldn't be displaying such errors, as they can be exploited.

## References

- http://php.net/mysqli-stmt.bind-param
- http://php.net/password_hash
- [How can I store my users' passwords safely?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1581610/how-can-i-store-my-users-passwords-safely)

Comment: Thanks man! It helped. It looks like I need to read about pdo and mysli differences ;)

Comment: Yes, the mysql libraries doesn't mix ;-) Even though some functions are very similar to one another. I recommend you learn both MySQLi and PDO, and use the one you find the easiest to work with, but there's certainly nothing wrong with using MySQLi as long as you bind your variables like that. *Cheers*

Answer (score 0):

Missing end of brackets at VALUES()

```
VALUES(:login, :passwd, FALSE, NOW(), NULL
VALUES(:login, :passwd, FALSE, NOW(), NULL)
```