# how can i get the value of COUNT(id)

Tags: php, mysql, object

I'm encountering a problem with this object. I don't know (if it is possible), how to get the value of `COUNT(id)`.

I tried `$req[0]->COUNT(id) but "COUNT()"` it detected it as a function. How could it be detect as a key?

Here's a var_dump($req):

```
object(stdClass)[4]
public 'COUNT(id)' => string '1' (length=1)
```

PHP

```
$req = $db->query('SELECT COUNT(id) FROM `users` WHERE username ="'.$username.'" AND password = "'.$password.'"');

if($req == 1){
 $_SESSION['authentificated'] = true;
 $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
}

var_dump($req);
```

The output of the query should be `0` or `1` if the user is already register or not.

Comment: You could alias the count - `SELECT COUNT(id) as userCount FROM users` then reference it as `$req[0]->userCount`

Comment: Dont write queries like that. Parameterize. Don't store plain text passwords, hash.

Comment: i dont undrestand why u check on the count, you can simply check if there is a user with given username and password

Comment: [how-can-i-store-my-users-passwords-safely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1581610/how-can-i-store-my-users-passwords-safely)

Comment: [how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.You need to add alias for `COUNT()`

2.After query execution you need to fetch record and then do the comparison

Do like below:-

```
$req = $db->query('SELECT COUNT(id) as count FROM `users` WHERE username ="'.$username.'" AND password = "'.$password.'"');

$result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($req); // sample example,you need to change accordingly
if($result['count'] == 1){
  //your code

}
```

Note:-

Saving plain password is very bad idea. so use [password hashing](https://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php)

Your current code is wide-open for SQL INJECTION. To prevent from it use `prepared statements`

[mysqli::prepare](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)

[PDO::prepare](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php)

***I will do it something like this:*** https://3v4l.org/YOBGX

Answer (score 0):

Here alias required or else it won't capture that count value the way you want.

```
$req = $db->query('SELECT COUNT(id) cnt FROM `users` WHERE username ="'.$username.'" AND password = "'.$password.'"');


var_dump($req);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution you have not bind the key for that please see below

```
 $req = $db->query('SELECT COUNT(id) as user_exists FROM `users` WHERE username 
="'.$username.'" AND password = "'.$password.'"');

if($req == 1){
    $_SESSION['authentificated'] = true;
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
}

var_dump($req);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this --

```
 $req = mysqli_query($db,'SELECT (COUNT(id)) as countID FROM `users` WHERE username ="'.$username.'" AND password = "'.$password.'"'));
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($req);
        $countID = $row['countID'];
        if($countID == 1){
         $_SESSION['authentificated'] = true;
         $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        }

        var_dump($req);
```